# c++ get/set method in class, Which data type I have to use?

Tags: c++

I have a class like below

```
class Circle{
   private:
    int radius;
    Circle* next
}
```

And I gonna creat set/get method...but i have no idea which data type i have to use.

```
int Circle::getRadius() const{return radius}
or 
int& Circle::getRadius() const{return radius}



void Circle::setRadius(int r) 
or 
void Circle::setRadius(int& r)  


CirCle* Circle::getNext() const{return next}
or 
Circle& Circle::getNext() const{return *(next)}



void Circle::setNext(Circle& circle)
{
    next = new Circle;
    next = circle;
 }
or 
void Circle::setRadius(Circle circle) 
{
    next = new Circle;
    next = circle;
}
or 
void Circle::setRadius(Circle* circle) 
{
    next = circle;
}
```

I'm famliar with Java quite a lot. And Java argument are all reference. But cpp is quite different so it drive me crazy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my opinion for basic types use passing value and getting variable by copy, for the others by ref or pointer to avoid copy bigger amount of memory.

Comment: Please consider whether your `Circle` class having a `next` member in the first place. It's very rare that you need internal linked lists, and they make issues of ownership complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You should use:*

```
int Circle::getRadius() const{return radius}
```

**Why?**
First because you don't want your getter to modify your object (that is done by the const after () ), and you don't want caller to your getter to be able to modify your radius either, in fact:

```
int& Circle::getRadius() const{return radius}
```

should not even compile. it would have to be:

```
const int& Circle::getRadius() const{return radius}
```

In this case the reference to radius returned is const and therefore, the caller cannot modify the radius via this getter.
Although it's totally correct, when dealing with primitive types in C++ one usually prefer to copy rather than to hold const reference. Why? because copy on primitive costs less than have to dereference it each time you need to use it.

*Use:*

```
void Circle::setRadius(int r)
```

**Why?**
Like before, using an int, prefere to copy the value to use a reference that you'll have to (implicitly) derefence on use.

*In this case*:

```
CirCle* Circle::getNext() const{return next}
or 
Circle& Circle::getNext() const{return *(next)}
```

**Why?** One thing is sure, you won't be able to use the second one, like in the first case your return value will have to be const Circle&. Plus, you want to be able to return a "invalid" value. In C++ not like in Java, you cannot return an "invalid" reference. So the best thing is to return a pointer which will have "NULL" value if "invalid".
After that, if you want your caller to be able to modify the "next Circle" you'll have to go with a Circle* return. If you don't want your caller to be able to modify the result you'll have to go with a const Circle*

```
const CirCle* Circle::getNext() const{return next}
or 
Circle* Circle::getNext() const{return next}
```

Some people think it's a bad thing to have a const method that return a non const pointer. For certain reasons, I don't, but both are syntaxly correct.

*Use:*

```
void Circle::setNext(Circle* circle) 
{
   next = circle;
}
```

**Why?** For your SetNext, it  depends on who will have to manage the memory (ie destruction) used by your "next circle" if it's an external class (I think it's the easiest), like a manager for exemple go with that

*For your setRadius, simply use:*

```
void Circle::setRadius(int value) 
{
    radius = value;
}
```

[Edit: ] Example of Circle class:
Here what would an external manager (like a Circle list) would look like:

```
class CircleList //Manager as I told
{
public:
    Circle* createCircle(int _radius)
    {
        Circle* circle = new circle(_radius);
        //manage here the add to the list of circle
    }

    void destroyCircle(Circle* _circle)
    {
        //Manage here the remove of the list
        delete _circle;
    }

    ~CircleList()
    {
        while( first )
        {
            destroyCircle(first);
        }
    }
private:
        Circle* first = NULL;
};

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(int _radius) : radius(_radius) {    }
    void setNext(Circle* _circle)
    {
        next = _circle;
    }
    Circle* getNext() const
    {
        return next;
    }
    void setRadius(int _value)
    {
        radius = _value;
    }
private:
    Circle* next = NULL;
    int radius = -1;
};
```

Here, only CircleList manage the list and memory used by circles. If you want to encapsulate even more, make setNext/getNext private and CircleList a friend of circle (once again some will judge, let them :p)

If you wanted to manage memory inside the Circle class, a circle would exist only if its predecessor exist, and if you delete one Circle you would delete all the ones after in the list(I can't see the application this...). In this case you would have something like:

```
 class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(int _radius) : radius(_radius) {    }
    void setNext(int _radius)
    {
        next = new Circle(radius);
    }
    void removeNext()
    {
        delete next;
        next = NULL;
    }
    Circle* getNext() const
    {
        return next;
    }
    void setRadius(int _value)
    {
        radius = _value;
    }

    ~Circle()
    {
        delete next;
    }
private:
    Circle* next = NULL;
    int radius = -1;
};
```

Note that you now have a destructor on circle and that when destroying one circle, it destroys all the circle that follow in the list (only way I see to avoid leak and external "holder" of circles)
Plus if you have a really long list, it may cause problems when destroying as a destructor calls (implicitly) the destructor of its successor, you may end up with a stack overflow.

That's why I was telling you that a manager external to the class was the best solution to me, but maybe some other people have better ideas :)

Comment: This is like, perfect answer ever.. Thanks alot

Comment: Question. about 'setNext' .. Class usually have destuctor which free all allocated memory.. But you said "memory management by external class is easiest".. Then the class don't need destructor?

Comment: And What if the '=' operator were defined? then, first and second setNext method is also valid, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, and next is "private" and i think it is impossible it's memory managing is done by external class.....

Comment: Ok so if I understand write your Circle class contains a next to do a List of circles? In this case maybe you should indeed do all memory management in your Circle class.

Comment: I'll edit my response to show you an example of what can be done.

Comment: I wouldn't do a = operator on such classes as there is a list management integrated to the class, I'd prefer to go with an explicit creation of new circle that init radius to the same value as the one you want to copy.

Answer (score 3):

First I'd just recommend going through some C++ tutorials. Your question is probably going to get downvoted here because it looks like you really didn't try to search for a solution to your problem, but rather just ask SO for help.

Need to understand a few things with C++. Learn pass by reference vs pass by value. Are primitives passed by reference or by value?

You also should look at pointers. You're kinda mixing up syntax in there a little bit. * is to de reference a pointer. & is to get the memory address of a certain object.

Explore these concepts and you'll find the answer to your question, and learn more about C++.

Try looking at this site for some info. 
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/84-access-functions-and-encapsulation/

If you have any other questions, feel free to let me know. :)
Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Java all are passed by value!

In case of references, it is passed the value of the reference. Because of that it is misunderstood generally.

In case of C++, you can return/pass by value or reference. In your example, int value would be returned by value simply; supposing that probably you would only need its value.

In case of a complex object, you could use reference or pointer. They are actually -almost- the same. You can find sources to look the differences in detail, but here let me tell simply: Pointers are kept in C++ to be compatible with C; references are considered instead. So, you could try to use references mostly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the difference of using values by copy and by reference and using pointers.

Passing values by copy, say:

```
int radius = 2;
setRadius( radius );
```

Creates a copy of 2 within the function. Whatever changes you do to that value within the function won't change the variable radius that you created outside.

Pointers hold a value that is the memory address of some variable. No matter the type you're using, a pointer only takes up 4 bytes in memory.

```
int radius = 2;
int *radiusPtr = &radius; // radiusPtr now points to the address of radius
std::cout << *radiusPtr << std::endl; // > 2
setRadius( radiusPtr ); // Passing a pointer to setRadius
```

Passing by reference is, in a way, similar to pointers but it's defined as "passing the variable itself". You could use a pointer to change the value of the pointed left value, but you can use a reference to change the values of the original variable. You could even use a reference to a pointer to change the original pointer.

```
int radius = 2;
setRadius( radius ); // Passing by reference is done in the same way as by value, the difference is the method signature -> setRadius( int &radius );
int &radiusRef = radius;
radiusRef = 3;
std::cout << radius << std::endl; // > 3
```

To answer what to use. Depends on your types and what you need.

```
//If you use a setter with reference, like
void setRadius( int& radius );

//You cannot pass literal values like
setRadius( 2 );
setRadius( int(2) );

//Only variables/lvalues
int radius = 2;
setRadius( radius );
```

If you are using a more complex structure then the reference, or a pointer, makes more sense. It's also more efficient to use a reference than it is to copy a huge structure.

The same applies when returning values. If you don't want the user to change the value of your attribute, then a pointer or reference are not the best option. But you could always use a const pointer or reference,

```
const int *getRadius() const;
const int &getRadius() const;
```

To prevent the user from changing the radius from outside, yet be able to use the value. The last const means that this function can be called even if you're using a const Circle, or const *Circle or const &Circle.

I'd say for ints you could just use copies, but for more complex structures, like the Circle, consider using references or pointers. In your case, you even store pointers to the next Circle, so a pointer should do.

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
class Circle{

    public:

        void SetRadius(int const& value){ radius = value;} // 1

        int GetRadius() const {return radius;} // 2

        void SetCircle(std::shared_ptr<Circle> const& pCircle) { next = pCircle;} // 3

        std::shared_ptr<Circle> GetCircle() { return next; } // 4 

    private:

        int radius;
        std::shared_ptr<Circle> next;
}
```

**1 and 3**   This is how you write set functions. Period.

**2 and 4**   Return by value and dont break the encapsulation

**3 and 4**   **NEVER** use raw pointers

Comment: Since it is 99% likely that this is an intrusive linked list of Circles (regardless of why one would do this to themselves), the next pointer should be non-owning. The advice to never use raw pointers is wrong in all situations where you need an observing (non-owning) pointer. Until the standard adopts some form of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf, that is.